# AngularJS returns length 0 for array with objects in it

Tags: angularjs, json, api

I am trying to dynamically set the type of page based on the number of articles available for that page. So, if i have 2 or more articles, give me the listing page, if i have one, just give me the details page. The thing is, even doe i can see my articles on the page, the `length` property always returns 0. Need a bit of help figuring this out. Here's the code for the entire controller:

so, this kind of works now: (see bellow the image for what I am getting in the console)

```
//Public page - List of articles
bordonHillControllers.controller('PageListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location' , 'Page_Articles', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $location, Page_Articles, $routeParams) {
    $scope.pageId = $routeParams.pageId;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var articles = Page_Articles.get({ id: $scope.pageId });
    deferred.resolve(articles);
    deferred.promise().then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.articles = data;
        if ([$scope.articles[0]].length == 1) {
            console.log([$scope.articles])
            //$location.path('/article/' + article.id);
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        return $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
    })
    $scope.formatDate = function (date) {
        var dateOut = new Date(date);
        return dateOut;
    };
}])
```

here is where I set up the service:

```
bordonHillServices.factory('Page_Articles', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/ArticlesByPageApi/', {}, {
          get: { method: 'GET', params: { id: 'pages' }, isArray: true },
      });
  }])
```

here is the service that is sending the data:

```
        //Get: Api/HomeApi
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var articles = await Task.FromResult(context.Articles.Where(p => p.Page_ID == id).Select(p => new { DatePublished = p.DatePublished, ID = p.ID, Image_ID = p.Image_ID, IsHomeFeatured = p.IsHomeFeatured, IsHomeMain = p.IsHomeMain, IsNewsFeatured = p.IsNewsFeatured, IsNewsMain = p.IsNewsMain, Page_ID = p.Page_ID, Preview = p.Preview, Title = p.Title, Image = context.Images.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == p.Image_ID) }).ToList());
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, articles);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could Not Load The Requested Data");
            throw ex;
        }
        return response;
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

So again, just to make sure I am clear: I need to return the number of articles in the `$scope.articles`.

I also tried `$scope.articles.data`(before using deffered, I thought since the api runs async that might be the issue but still doesn't work).

this is the template for the html:

```
$templateCache.put(
'~/Views/Home/pageList.cshtml',

'<section id="appContent" ng-controller="PageListCtrl">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="form-group form-horizontal" style="display: flex;">' +
            '<label class="padding10">Search: </label>' +
            '<input class="padding10 form-control" style="display:inline" ng-model="query">' +
            '<label class="padding10">Order: </label>' +
            '<select class="padding10 form-control" style="display:inline" ng-model="orderProp">' +
                '<option value="title">Alphabetical</option>' +
                '<option value="datePublished">By Date</option>' +
            '</select>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
        '<div ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | filter: { isNewsFeatured : false}" class="col-md-12 article-listing">' +
            '<br /><br />' +
            '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2" ng-if="article.image.path">' +
                '<a href="#/article/{{article.id}}" class="thumb thumbnail">' +
                    '<img ng-src="{{article.image.path}}" alt="{{article.title}} image:">' +
                '</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<a href="#/article/{{article.id}}"><h3>{{article.title}}</h3></a>' +
            '<p class="publishedDate">Published on: <span ng-bind="formatDate(article.datePublished) | date"></span></p>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-10 preview">{{article.preview}}</div>' +
            '<br />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="buttons">' +
            '<a href="#/article/{{article.id}}">Read more...</a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '<hr />' +
    '</div>' +
'</section>'
)
```

It all works, i am getting 2 articles listed(that's how many i have set for this page) but length it's still 0;
[image: i am getting an array of json object from the service]

Comment: try removing "successCallback". from this function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) to this function(data, status, headers, config)

Comment: @per.eight How will renaming a function help?

Comment: You should provide an example of the XHR request return data. 
Also, what is Page_Articles, is it just a $http resource?

Comment: `Page_Articles.get({ id: $scope.pageId })` returns a promise...? Looks like you have some code after a return statement. What is its purpose?!

Comment: yup, Page_Articles is my $http service

Comment: If data.length is 0, data might be a wrapper object. Have you inspected data using `console.dir(data)`?

Comment: `return deferred.promise().then`, i think promise is an object, not a funtion.. So: `return deferred.promise.then()`

Comment: *"I need to return the number of articles in the $scope.articles"* - to what are you returning this data from a controller..?! I don't see you resolving the promise with any data but you're just redirecting. It's not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: i removed return, still 0, added `console.dir(data)` says: `[object aray] length 0`

Comment: promise is a method, just tried without `()`, also, TJ, i am getting the data from a service `Page_Articles` and adding them to the scope, that's it, later i'm working that scope in a template. I do get the articles on my page so that works, it's just the length that comes back 0. In my console, i am checking the network tab and i get an aray of json objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's some stuff going wrong, I think there are some misconceptions about promises.

First you create a deferred, which you resolve yourself immediately afterwards:

```
deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred.resolve(Page_Articles.get({ id: $scope.pageId }));
```

The promise should be resolved after the get request finishes and by the service, not by your controller!

`Page_Articles.get({ id: $scope.pageId })` might itself return a promise (I don't know this), but whatever it returns, you probably resolve `deferred` before the get-Request finishes.

So deferred will be resolved with an empty object I suppose (the code for Page_Articles would be helpful!). This is why `data.length` is 0.

```
return deferred.promise().then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {
    // Data might be a promise
    $scope.articles = data;
    //...
```

Also you don't need to return inside a controller. I don't know what that results in.

As to why you see your articles, there might be something happening in the service. Not sure.

**EDIT1**

Page_Articles returns an angular-style promise. This is indeed an array, I'll get to that later. Anyways, here's how it should work:

```
//Public page - List of articles
bordonHillControllers.controller('PageListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location' , 'Page_Articles', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $location, Page_Articles, $routeParams) {
    $scope.pageId = $routeParams.pageId;

    // Added var, the $promise attribute is what we want
    var deferred = Page_Articles.get({ id: 1 }).$promise;

    // After loading, assign the data
    // I've removed the other params, they were adequate for jQuery promises
    // Couldn't find the correct signature for $resource
    deferred.then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.articles = data;
        if ($scope.articles.length == 1) {
            $location.path('/article/' + $scope.articles[0].id);
        }
        alert(data.length)
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        return $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
    })

    $scope.formatDate = function (date) {
        var dateOut = new Date(date);
        return dateOut;
    };
}])
```

The reason for the array type, is that you can assign $resources like this (a shorthand):

```
$scope.articles = Page_Articles.get({ id: 1 });
```

As long as it doesn't finish, the length is zero. When it's resolved, the array is automatically filled.

**EDIT 2:**

The shorthand is the building ground for why you saw the articles (this was tricky!). You resolved the deferred with the angular promise (zero length array). This was then assigned to `$scope.articles`. When it resolved the articles showed up automatically (a feature of the shorthand).

**Yeah, I got it!**

Another thing you could optimize: You're using `.get()`, to query an array. Ideally this is done using `.query()`. You can then use `.get()` for single items (as in REST). I think it's possible to pass params into query if you need to.

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'promise'`, give me 2 minutes to add the code for the service and for the template that reads the data :)

Comment: This docs page is also helpful: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q , $q is the promise implementation used by $resource, and it explains the concepts pretty good I think

Comment: I found something but still needs some work, had to use brackets like `[$scope.articles]` but now it's all inside another array and i'm struggling to get inside :) in the console i get something like `object Array [Array[0]]` and inside of that are my articles, but doing something like `[$scope.articles[0]]` gives me "undefined".

Comment: Please add your current code. I thought I had spotted the issue. Template and Backend are probably not necessary for that matter ;)

Comment: Okay, your new code is a mix up mine and your old code. You can really live without `$.Deferred()`. Page_Articles already implements that same functionality. I encourage you to read my explanation closely and use only the code below EDIT1

Comment: yup, you did it, i love you mate :D... thx a lot. your code works, i get the right length for the array :D